# Picking foliage from street/motorway trees or street overhang

Tags: england-and-wales

I want to take a few branches from a particular tree which overhangs a public pavement. It is for my own personal flower arrangement and not for commercial purposes. My understanding is that whilst the owner can be forced by a local authority to trim back anything which obstructs people on the pavement or vehicles on the road, the branches will nevertheless still technically belong to them.
My other option is to take branches from trees/bushes in a park/woods/street. Looking at it is 'foraging', I would be permitted to take fruit/foliage which will re-grow (i.e. one cannot uproot a whole plant), for personal, non-commercial, use. However, y understanding is that this is only true for  that is only on common land where one has the permission of the owner to collect it. A park may grant permission to walk through, but not to pick. Similarly, most roads and verges where the trees are growing actually belong to the Crown and are governed by the Highways Authority or Local Authorities, who do not give express permission for foraging.
Do I have this right or are there any other options for me?

Comment: Other options?   Ask the owner of the tree whether you can take the branches and, if so, at what price, if any.

Comment: If it's the local authority, who can one ask and get a proper authoritative answer?

Comment: Related: [Picking fruit that overhangs public property](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/84290/picking-fruit-that-overhangs-public-property).

Comment: foraging says you can't damage the plant, which cutting a branch is.